# Magento: How to add text before price

Tags: magento

I have a shop with configurable Products.
In the category page with all my products, I want to add text before the price.
How can I do that? I use the Modern theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can look in
>
> ```
> app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
> ```

if your theme in have no file use 
    you can look in

> ```
> \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml
> ```

```
Around line 189 you will find the following:

<span id=”product-price-<?php echo $_id ?>
<?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>”>

Just add the following above the line:

<?php echo $this->__(‘Your Text Goes Here:’) ?>
```

> ```
> so that you have something like this:
> ```

```
<?php echo $this->__(‘Your Text Goes Here:’) ?>
<span class=”regular-price” id=”product-price-<?php echo $_id ?>
<?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>”>

Your text will be reflected before the price in both 
the catalog and the product page.
```

Comment: If we add <?php echo $this->__(‘Your Text Goes Here:’) ?> in price.phtml its show in both product listing and product detail page. But here user2614716 want to add only in product listing page only.

Answer (score 1):

add your text before  getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>  in catalog/product/list.phtm

Something like following :

```
  <?php echo "YOUR TEXT" ?>
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Comment: From your theme folder if its not present there then change in base file.

Answer (score 0):

**In magento 2**, You need to make changes in `price-box.js` which is placed at

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js

Make sure you take this js in your custom theme folder and make changes on line number 22 near 
`priceTemplate: '<span class="price"><%- data.formatted %></span>'`

Add your custom text after `<span class="price">`

Some thing like this,

```
priceTemplate: '<span class="price">Price - <%- data.formatted %></span>'
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

For adding label before price you need to override final_price.phtml file in your custom theme -

Core file path -

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

Override in your custom theme -

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

Change code as below -

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Custom Label 1 : '),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Custom Label 2 : '),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Custom Label 3 : '),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl() ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here I have change text in below code also added in this code in last else condition as it was not present in else condition.

> 'display_label'     => __('Custom Label 3 : '),

Thanks